# how to insert/add results from user defined function to JTextArea in Java

Tags: java, user-defined-functions

I have created a function e.g. `findsimilirity()` in class `data_parser.java` and used for loop for results through `System.out.println()`. Now i need to display these results in `JTextArea`  that was used in main class `GUIWEB.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to return the value you want instead of printing it.

Then use

```
JTextAreaName.setText("Result is: " + return_val);
```

Comment: public void findsimilirity() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tfidfDocsVector.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tfidfDocsVector.size(); j++) {
             
               System.out.println("between " + i + " and " + j + "  =  " + new CosineSimilarity().cosineSimilarity
                                       (
                                         tfidfDocsVector.get(i), 
                                         tfidfDocsVector.get(j)
                                       )
                                  );

          
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: I wanted to add this output on JtextArea

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype of your function to String then 
JTextAreaVariableName.setText(findsimilirity());

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more understanding.

Comment: when i change it create problem.